# How to make faster my script on python?

Tags: python, performance, parallel-processing

I have a script in python but it takes more than 20 hours to run until the end.

Since my code is pretty big, I will post a simplified one.

The first part of the code:

```
flag = 1
mydic = {}
for i in mylist:
    mydic[flag] = myfunction(i)
    flag += 1
```

`mylist` has more than 700 entries and each time I call `myfunction` it run for around 20sec.

So, I was thinking if I can use paraller programming to split the iteration into two groups and run it simultaneously. Is that possible and will I need the half time than before?

The second part of the code:

```
mymatrix = []
for n1 in range(0,flag):
    mat = []
    for n2 in range(0,flag):
        if n1 >= n2:
            mat.append(0)
        else:
            res = myfunction2(mydic(n1),mydic(n2))
            mat.append(res)
    mymatrix.append(mat)
```

So, if `mylist` has 700 entries, I want to create a 700x700 matrix where it is upper triangular matrix. But the `myfunction2()` needs around 30sec each time. I don't know if I can use parallel programming here too.

I cannot simplify the `myfunction()` and `myfunction2()` since they are functions where I call an external api and return the results.

Do you have any suggestion of how can I change it to make it faster.

Comment: Parallel processing will only help if you have multiple cores.

Comment: @Linuxios: ... so it applies only to almost any PC produced in the last 8 years...

Comment: @MatteoItalia: Still worth mentioning. And I wouldn't say 8 years. Only high end computers have had them that long.

Comment: @Linuxios Yes. I have a dual core PC.

Comment: @Tasos: So you can expect better performance if you thread it to two levels of paralelism.

Comment: What exactly does `myfunction` to do take 20 seconds?

Comment: @KennyTM It is a dictionary and each entity is a dictionary too. Each inside dictionaries have 4-5 keys. I could use a list for the outside dictionary since it doesn't help a lot, but does this improve the performance?

Comment: @poke the first one call an external api and return a json. I keep only few from the json and return those data. The second function do a statistic analysis but I cannot make it faster. Since, I have to use a certain algorithm.

Comment: @Tason I mean what kind of processing happens inside? Is it heavy CPU work, or does it involve I/O on the disk or even over a network?

Comment: @poke As I said, the first is just an external api and a small changes on this so I can use the data I want. The problem here is the api and not the changes I do. As for the second function I am calling an API again and use a TFIDF algorithm on the results. I don't believe that they are too heavy as functions. The real problem on both of them are the externals API. That's why I thought of the parallel computing since I cannot do many things on the functions

Comment: To be sure, run a profiler like cProfile.  By the way, if you run two streams of processing (with two cores) you will not get a halving of wall-clock runtime - parts of your processing will still be serial, usually at start and end.

Comment: Have you looked at the [`multiprocessing`](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) standard library? If not, I implore you to try it out and post an update with what you have tried.

Comment: @cdarke I don't know what cProfile is but I will google it and try to add it in my code

Comment: @sigmavirus24 I haven't used it yet. I will do it tonight and see if I can improve it. I will update my post if I have a problem or if I manage to make it faster

Comment: Can any of the values be pre-computed and put into a table?

Comment: @PaulGriffiths Nope. The function2 needs the results of the function1. I don't have any data to precompute anything. I create them on the fly.

Comment: @Tasos: I mean, does `function1()` typically return some common values that you'll typically need, even if you're not sure you're going to need them. I'm not sure what `mylist` would contain, but if it only ever contained numbers between 1 and 100, then you could precompute some of the results since they'll often come up. If `mylist` could contain anything between 1 and 700 billion, this'll be a bit less practical.

Comment: @Tasos: sigmavirus24 raises a good point below.  Are you using Python 2 or Python 3?  If Python 2, then you should be using `xrange` rather than `range` - `range` is correct for Python 3.  Might not make much difference, but every little bit helps.

Comment: @cdarke it would only affect "start-up" time really. The main optimization should be how he actually executes the internals of the loop. Those definitely sound like the major bottle neck. My comment is really just a very minor optimization that probably will end up saving on the order of milliseconds. If (on Python 2) I do `time python -c 'range(0, 700)'` it takes about 0.03s

Comment: @cdarke I am using python 2.7. I will change the range to xrange. Even the smallest difference is a difference :)

Comment: @Tasos: make sure you benchmark each change you make, and only change one thing at a time.

Comment: @cdarke I will include a timer and I will run the code for a sample of the data to test it before. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, I think it's very likely that the 30seconds of time is mostly due to external API calls.  I would add some timing code to test what portions of your code are actually responsible for the slowness.

If it is from the external API calls, there are some easy fixes.  The external API calls block, so you'll get a speedup if you can move to a parallel model ( though 30s of blocking sounds huge to me ).

I think it would be easiest to create a quick "task list" by having the output of 2 loops be a matrix of arguments to pass into a function.  Then I'd pipe them into `Celery` to run the tasks.  That should give you a decent speedup with a minimal amount of work.

You would probably save a lot more time with the `threading` or `multiprocessing` modules to run tasks (or sections) , or even write it all in `Twisted` python - but that usually takes longer than a simple celery function.

The one caveat with the `Celery` approach is that you'll be dispatching a lot of work - so you'll have to have some functionality to poll for results. That could be a `while` loop that just `sleeps(10)` and repeats itself until celery has a result for every task.  If you do it in `Twisted`, you can access/track results on finish.  I've never had to do something like this with multiprocessing, so don't know how that would fit in.

Answer (score 0):

how about using a generator for the second part instead of one of the for loops

```
def fn():
    for n1 in range(0, flag):
        yield n1

generate = fn()

while True:
    a = next(generate)
    for n2 in range(0, flag):
        if a >= n2:
            mat.append(0)
        else:
            mat.append(myfunction2(mydic(a),mydic(n2))
            mymatrix.append(mat)
```

Comment: I doubt this improves the performance since `range` on python2 will return a list regardless. If he's on python3, `range` is already an iterator and will provide the performance boost I can only assume you're thinking of.